# Split String into it's words

Tags: c, arrays, string, split

I have a long text as string and I want to split it into it's single words using C.
I tried solution withs `strtok()` but this on feels like a dirty solution for me with all the pointer madness. 
Is there a straight forward solution to split a string into it's words and store them in an array?

I thought about a for loop which iterates the string and starts a new "counter" when a whitespace or full stop appears but I alaways get confused when it comes to storing it...

Hope you can help me

Comment: `strtok` is the correct approach.  I'm afraid you'll have to get used to "pointer madness" if you're going to program in C

Comment: strtok is not always the best option for 2 reasons.  It clobbers the original string, and it's not thread safe.  But if you can live with that then strtok works and if you don't want to clobber the original string make a copy first with strdup and pass that to strtok instead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can process the string like this. This is just a simple demonstration. So you may need to refine the code before putting it to practical use.

```
#define skip_white_space(p)               \
    do {                                  \
        while (*p != '\0' && isspace(*p)) \
            ++p;                          \
    } while (0)

#define skip_non_space(p)                  \
    do {                                   \
        while (*p != '\0' && !isspace(*p)) \
            ++p;                           \
    } while (0)

#define WORD_MAXLEN 64

char **strsplit(char *text, int *nword)
{
    char *p, *q, **words;

    words = NULL;
    *nword = 0;

    p = text;
    while (*p != '\0') {
        skip_white_space(p);
        q = p;
        skip_non_space(p);
        if (p > q) {
            ++*nword;
            words = (char **)realloc(words, *nword * sizeof(*words));
            words[*nword - 1] = (char *)malloc(WORD_MAXLEN);
            strncpy(words[*nword - 1], q, p - q);
            words[*nword - 1][p - q] = '\0';
        }
        skip_white_space(p);
    }

    return words;
}
```

Comment: Looks good! Candidate refinements - but not really to take away from a sound answer.: 1) `malloc(WORD_MAXLEN) ... strncpy()`.  Change to `malloc(p-q+1) ... memcpy(words[*nword - 1], q, p - q);` 2) `const char *text` 3) delete 2nd `skip_white_space(p);` 4) drop cast before `realloc() & malloc()` 5) drop `WORD_MAXLEN`

Comment: @chux So, you mean the following right? 1) to reduce unnecessary memory allocation, and prevent the copying from being stopped by '\0'; 2) to leave the original string untouched; 3) to remove useless calls; 4) to remove useless casts; 5) to remove useless macros because of 1); Thanks :)

Comment: Yes on all except "stopped by '\0'".  Since there is not `\0` from `q` to `&q[p-q-1]`.  #1 was also to prevent problem should the sub-string exceed `WORD_MAXLEN`.